# How to stop data duplication when using big query safe_divide logic to manipulate data?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My problem is that I start to receive data duplication on after I add in some logic (safe_divide) in my big query # standard SQL statement? This problem only occurs after I add in this line

```
SAFE_DIVIDE( u.weekly_capacity/25200, 1) AS TargetDailyHours
```

If I don't solve this I may just have to write all the logic within data studio as the current workflow is Harvest -> Stitch-> Bigquery->data studio

In this query, I am using a left join of the table `time_entires` on MAX(updated_at) or most recent time entry, to a full join of the table `users`  where a user is currently active. I wish to actually manipulate the data so that I could find FTE actual hours worked/ weekly_capacity. But any time I write logic or big query functions I get duplications in the results?

```
SELECT DISTINCT outer_e.hours, outer_e.id, outer_e.updated_at, 
                outer_e.spent_date, outer_e.created_at, 
                outer_e.client_id, outer_e.user_id AS harvest_userid,
                u.is_admin, u.first_name, u.is_active, u.id AS user_id, 
                u.weekly_capacity,
                client.name as names,

--SAFE_DIVIDE( u.weekly_capacity /25200, 1) AS TargetDailyHours

FROM
  (SELECT  e.id, MAX(e.updated_at) AS updated_at FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS e   
  GROUP BY e.id LIMIT 1000
  ) AS inner_e

LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS outer_e
ON inner_e.id = outer_e.id AND inner_e.updated_at = outer_e.updated_at
FULL JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT id, first_name, weekly_capacity, is_active, is_admin FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.users`WHERE is_active = true
) AS u
ON outer_e.user_id = u.id  

JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id , 
         name FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.clients`) AS client
ON outer_e.client_id = client.id
```

The Column weekly capacity  in results will start to show people with different weekly capacity numbers for instance

```
Row hours   id  updated_at  spent_date  created_at  client_id   harvest_userid  is_admin    first_name  is_active   user_id weekly_capacity TargetDailyHours    

1   
0.22
995005338
2019-05-07 15:14:13 UTC
2019-04-29 00:00:00 UTC
2019-04-29 15:30:40 UTC
6864491
2622223
false
Nolan
true
2622223
72000
2.857142857142857


2   
0.22
995005338
2019-05-07 15:14:13 UTC
2019-04-29 00:00:00 UTC
2019-04-29 15:30:40 UTC
6864491
2622223
false
Nolan
true
2622223
129600
5.142857142857143
```

In this result the user Nolan will show up two-time entries with the sequence number of 995005338 with 0.22 hours and the weekly_capacity number will change from 129600 in ROW:2 to 72000 in ROW:1

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is with the u.weekly_capacity column, it has two or more different values for the same user. The SAFE_DIVIDE operation is only reflecting this issue.

You can track this duplicate value to your "u" subquery:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id, first_name, weekly_capacity, is_active, is_admin 
    FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.users`
    WHERE is_active = true
```

The users table contains two or more rows with the same id where `is_active=true`. This seems to be an issue with the data, so in order to avoid the duplicate rows you have to decide which one is the value you want to keep. For example, if you would like to keep only the maximum value you can use GROUP BY:

```sql
SELECT id, first_name, MAX(weekly_capacity) as weekly_capacity, is_active, is_admin
    FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.users`
    WHERE is_active = true
    GROUP BY id, first_name, is_active, is_admin
```

Additionally, if your users table have enough information you can use other columns to further narrow the results

For example:

```sql
...
LEFT JOIN `harvest-experiment.harvest.time_entries` AS outer_e
    ON inner_e.id = outer_e.id AND inner_e.updated_at = outer_e.updated_at
FULL JOIN ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT id, first_name, weekly_capacity, is_active, is_admin, last_updated
        FROM `harvest-experiment.harvest.users` WHERE is_active = true
) AS u
ON outer_e.user_id = u.id AND outer_e.updated_at = u.last_updated
...
```